# Pip installs are met with SSL errors

Tags: installation, python, ssl

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm trying to run a package for my adata analysis. I'm currently using Python 3.7 installed through the Anaconda. Since installing this way, I can't acquire any modules using *pip.* Every attempt is met with an SSL error. If I install Python through another source (direct download of Python 3.7) I don't run into this error, but when running the package it has several errors in accessing the necessary modules. Because of this, I would like to take advantage of the large number of modules available in Anaconda, which seems to let the package run but not execute as several modules are out of date. I'm not sure if trying to fix the SSL error in the Anaconda version of Python/pip would be easier than trying to configure a separate install of Python interpreter to work with those packages. Any advice?

Comment: [Cannot update or install anything with pip, SSL error](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Cannot-update-or-install-anything-with-pip-SSL-error)

Comment: I managed to fix it by doing an install of Python 3.7 from the website (not Anaconda). The Anaconda install of Python seems to be the issue. Changing the trusted hosts for pip did not enable me to update it or install packages.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the trusted hosts for pip did not enable me to update it or install new packages. I managed to fix it by installing Python 3.7 from https://www.python.org/ (not Anaconda) and updating the PATH variables. The Anaconda install of Python seems to be the issue.